# put and align equally pics in a row

Tags: html, css

Using the structure below, the pictures are not spaced  evenly in the row.

On the image you see there are more space between the 2nd and 3rd image

I used the following code.

css:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 712px;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" >
      <div class="col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg?text=Placeholder" align="left"></div>
      <div class="col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg?text=Placeholder" align="center"></div>
      <div class="col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg?text=Placeholder"  align="right"></div>
    </div>
```

[the spaces among pictures are not equal PLS see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfrrl.jpg)

Comment: add `class='img-responsive` to your images since you are using bootstrap

Comment: In this case just removing inline styling (align="...") is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using flexbox for this:

```
<div class="row pics-container" >
  <div class="col-4 pic-wrapper"><img src="images/thmb1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="col-4 pic-wrapper"><img src="images/thmb1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="col-4 pic-wrapper"><img src="images/thmb1.jpg"></div>
</div>


.pics-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.pic-wrapper {
  align-self: center;
}
```

A concise and detailed example page for this CSS technique exists here: [Flexbox Playground](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv)

Comment: hi, thx now the palaces among pics are fine but the pics don't fill the whole row https://imgur.com/a/vJLJr

Answer (score 1):

You can evenly space items with `justify-content: space-between` <sup>[[reference]](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/#article-header-id-1)</sup>.  The main issue with your code is the `align` attributes on the `div` elements.  Align is fighting the other layout code and causing that strange spacing.

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 712px;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.col-4 {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" >
      <div class="col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg?text=Placeholder"></div>
      <div class="col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg?text=Placeholder"></div>
      <div class="col-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg?text=Placeholder"></div>
    </div>
```